# JIRA Board with quick filter using a lookup control for projects

Tags: jira

We have a JIRA board (Kanban) that has many Projects on it that the team work on interchangably, these are added to the board using a custom filter which is based on specific tags on the issues.

I want to be able to create a quick filter the current board, by one or more Projects at a time, the same way that can be done in the Issue Search, ie using the Project drop down.

The alternate to this is to be able to create a custom swimlane where each project is grouped together, but I don't want this setting on by default, so the quick filter option would be much better. I have tried to create the Swimlane using custom query containg the JQL "ORDER BY project ASC", but this only creates one group called Projects, not a group for each project.

Answer (score 0):

The board shows issues matching the intersection of active filters, not the union, so the approach I'd suggest is to have filters of the form `PROJECT != your_project_name`, titled "Hide your_project_name" so that people select the filters for projects they aren't interested in, leaving the ones they are showing.

Comment: We have "many projects" appearing on the same board, I want to be able to toggle between them easily and see which ones are ready for release.  So creating an individual filter to either include or exclude certain projects is not what I want.

Comment: I agree that it may not be what you want; per the above comment, though, I'm not sure you can get what you want, so this may be a workable substitute. There might be an add-on that provides the feature you're hoping for, but I don't know of one. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Don't think you can do that.  A quick filter is literally a link - it's can't be rendered as a drop down list.  And it is, as is titled, a "filter".  So each filter you click the link for restricts to cards that match that filter.  Quick Filter just doesn't have functionality to do what you want.

Swimlanes is closer to what you want.  Swimlanes can be individually expanded or collapsed, and there is also a expand all and collapse all option on the Board menu.

Also, if you are having to manage a lot of different projects on one board - you might take a look at JIRA Portfolio.